# time.sleep() and BackGround Windows PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, sleep

given that, I'm starting with the PyQt5 module, I'm still slowly understanding the logic behind it. That said, I'm having a problem that I can not find an answer to and I hope you can help me.
I have this script:

```
import sys, socket, time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from io import BytesIO as by

class loadGame(QWidget):
    wLoadDisplay = 768
    hLoadDisplay = 576
    wLoadBar = 650
    hLoadBar = 40

    pbarCSS = """
    QProgressBar
    {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #FFF;
        border: 4px solid #000;
        text-align: center;
    }
    QProgressBar::chunk
    {
        background-color: #FF0000;
        width: 1px;
    }
    """

    labelCSS = """
    QLabel
    {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #FFF;
        border: 4px solid #000;
    }
    """

    fileResource = []
    imgResource = []
    vidResource = []
    audResource = []
    diaResource = []
    txtResource = []

    internetConnection = False

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.outputFile = by()

        self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.pbar.setGeometry((self.wLoadDisplay / 2 - self.wLoadBar / 2), (self.hLoadDisplay / 2 - self.hLoadBar * 2),
                              self.wLoadBar, self.hLoadBar)
        self.pbar.setFormat("%v/%m")
        self.pbar.setValue(0)
        self.pbar.setStyleSheet(self.pbarCSS)

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setGeometry((self.wLoadDisplay / 2 - self.wLoadBar / 2), (self.hLoadDisplay / 2),
                               self.wLoadBar, self.hLoadBar)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label.setStyleSheet(self.labelCSS)

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, self.wLoadDisplay, self.hLoadDisplay)
        oImage = QImage("bgloading.png")
        sImage = oImage.scaled(QSize(self.wLoadDisplay, self.hLoadDisplay))
        palette = QPalette()
        palette.setBrush(10, QBrush(sImage))
        self.setPalette(palette)

        qtRectangle = self.frameGeometry()
        centerPoint = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qtRectangle.moveCenter(centerPoint)
        self.move(qtRectangle.topLeft())

        self.run()

    def run(self):
        self.checkConnection()
        if self.internetConnection:
            self.checkUpdate()
        else:
            pass

    def checkConnection(self):
        self.objectChange("Check Internet Connection", 1)
        try:
            host = socket.gethostbyname("www.google.it")
            s = socket.create_connection((host, 80), 2)
            self.internetConnection = True
        except:
            pass

        self.count()
        self.reset()

    def checkUpdate(self):
        pass

    def objectChange(self, object, n):
        self.label.setText(object)
        self.pbar.setMaximum(n)

    def count(self):
        self.pbar.setValue(self.pbar.value() + 1)

    def reset(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        self.pbar.setMaximum(0)
        self.pbar.setValue(0)
        self.label.setText("...")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loadDisplay = QApplication(sys.argv)
    load = loadGame()
    load.show()
    sys.exit(loadDisplay.exec_())
```

Searching on the web, I discovered that the problem is related to "time.sleep (2)", that is, the instruction blocks the window that does not appear until two seconds have passed.
The fact is that I would like to spend one or two seconds, showing the completion of the bar, before resetting and move on to the next statement contained in "def run (self)".
So, is there a way to make that pause, without using the Time module? I do not know, maybe with QTimer? I repeat, I do not know much about PyQt5 yet, so I'm not aware if QTimer can do the same thing.
If QTimer can not do it, is it possible in any other way? I would like to avoid the "threads" of PyQt5, because I read that it would be possible to do it, but I would like to avoid using it only for the Timer module.
I only add one more question, to avoid opening another one and publishing the same script.
In the script, the window background is done via "oImage = QImage (" bgloading.png ")" etc.
I noticed, however, that if the file name were found to be wrong, or the file itself is missing, the background is colored black. So, if there are any errors (wrong name or missing file) it's possible set a background, for example, white?
Because when the window is loaded with "this error", no exception is raised and the script continues.
Edit: I've edited the published script so that it contains only the PyQt5 part, so you can try it out. Obviously only the image is missing, which can be replaced with any image.
Unfortunately I had forgotten to write that the part where "self.set_display ()" was reported was to show that once the work performed by PyQt5 was terminated, it would be closed (which was still missing, because using Pycharm I would close the execution of the script from the program). The script would continue by calling the "self.set_display ()" function.

Edit2: I tried, as suggested, to replace "time.sleep (2)", but I get the same result. The problem is that if I do not put the pause, the window appears normally, but the reset happens too quickly and the user does not see the filling of the progress bar. If instead I put "time.sleep (2)" or, the suggested solution, the window appears only after the pause, that is when the reset has already occurred.

Comment: Do not combine libraries, it is immaterial to make such software.

Comment: PyQt5 uses it at the beginning of the script only to load the file "in memory", then it is closed and continues with Pygame. There is no combination or nothing, but it is as if they were separate.

Comment: OK, you could show a code that can run to see what is the best option, yours is not currently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An expression equivalent to `time.sleep(2)` that is friendly to PyQt is as follows:

```
loop = QEventLoop()
QTimer.singleShot(2000, loop.quit)
loop.exec_()
```

---

The problem is caused because you are showing the widget after the pause, you must do it before calling `run()`, Also another error is to use `QImage`, for questions of widgets you must use `QPixmap`.

If the file does not exist then `QPixmap` will be null and to know if it is you should use the `isNull()` method:

```
    [...]

    self.setGeometry(0, 0, self.wLoadDisplay, self.hLoadDisplay)
    palette = self.palette()
    pixmap = QPixmap("bgloading.png")
    if not pixmap.isNull():
        pixmap = pixmap.scaled(QSize(self.wLoadDisplay, self.hLoadDisplay))
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.Window, QBrush(pixmap))
    else:
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.Window, QBrush(Qt.white))
    self.setPalette(palette)

    qtRectangle = self.frameGeometry()
    centerPoint = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
    qtRectangle.moveCenter(centerPoint)
    self.move(qtRectangle.topLeft())
    self.show()

    self.run()

[...]

def reset(self):
    loop = QEventLoop()
    QTimer.singleShot(2000, loop.quit)
    loop.exec_()
    self.pbar.setMaximum(0)
    self.pbar.setValue(0)
    self.label.setText("...")
```

Comment: I should put the instruction in place of "time.sleep (2)" right?

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately I get the same problem. However I modified the question, so as to include only the PyQt5 part.

Comment: I'm a stupid, I focused on the fact of the pause and I did not think I had to move the instruction "show ()". Thanks for the information regarding "QImage" and "QPixmap". Unfortunately, even with this correction, if the file is missing, no exception or error is raised, so I can not intervene, perhaps changing the background color or other.

Comment: Once again, "Tanto di cappello" as I say in Italian (I can not honestly say it in English XD) Joking aside, I thank you once again for your precious help.

Comment: how to import qeventloop? AttributeError: type object 'QObject' has no attribute 'QEventLoop'

Comment: @FoggyMindedGreenhorn QEventLoop is present in QtCore. you can either import it from QtCore or directly use it by the `QtCore.QEventLoop` method. PS: QTimer is also present in QtCore.